# How do I detect the last line using fgetcsv?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm trying to convert a csv file into GeoJSON and then display the results on a Google map.

The last feature in the feature collection shouldn't have a comma after it so I need to detect which is the last line in fgetcsv and have leave off the comma and I'm struggling with this.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php   
     $file = fopen("Incident_List.csv","r");

     echo "{<br>";
     echo "\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",<br>";
     echo "\"features\": [<br>";

    $csvflag = true;
    while(! feof($file))
      {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        if($csvflag) { $csvflag = false; continue; }
        echo "{<br>";
            echo "\"geometry\": {<br>";
            echo "\"type\": \"Point\",<br>";
            echo "\"coordinates\": [<br>";
        echo $data[2] . "," . $data[1] . "<br>";
        echo "]<br>";
        echo "},<br>";
        echo "\"type\": \"Feature\",<br>";
            echo "\"properties\": {<br>";
            echo "\"Category\":\"" . $data[4] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Grid Reference\":\"" . $data[0] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Day\":\"" . $data[3] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Date\":\"" . $data[4] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Type Of Incident\":\"" . $data[5] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Area\":\"" . $data[7] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Sex\":\"" . $data[8] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Age\":\"" . $data[9] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Members\":\"" . $data[10] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Hours\":\"" . $data[11] . "\",<br>";
            echo "\"Notes\":\"" . $data[12] . "\",<br>";
            echo "}<br>";
            echo "},<br>";

    }       

      }
    fclose($file);
      ?>
```

And this is an example of the output I am trying to achieve:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -3.224752,
          55.891831
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "misper",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam erat non tellus pellentesque, non euismod quam lacinia. Sed ac ex non eros aliquam sagittis. Etiam iaculis turpis sit amet arcu viverra, ac cursus sem feugiat. Sed fermentum dolor non mauris semper, eu pulvinar dolor feugiat.",
        "name": "Missing Person",
        "phone": "+44 20 1234 5678"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -2.631056,
          55.243980
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "walker",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam erat non tellus pellentesque, non euismod quam lacinia. Sed ac ex non eros aliquam sagittis. Etiam iaculis turpis sit amet arcu viverra, ac cursus sem feugiat. Sed fermentum dolor non mauris semper, eu pulvinar dolor feugiat.",
        "name": "Injured Walker",
        "phone": "+44 20 1234 5678"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put the `,` at the beginning if $csvflag = false

Comment: Dude, build an array and then `json_encode` it!

Comment: And all those `<br>` are going to choke whatever is receiving this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As per my comment to Don't Panic below. I tried using json_encode earlier but it wraps the coordinates in quotes and GeoJSON falls over if I do this. Note: the <br> were just to output it the browser and won't go in the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something more like this rather than manually writing out your own JSON.

Append your data to a PHP array, and use the built-in `json_encode` function to create the JSON.

```
$file = fopen("Incident_List.csv","r");

$features = [];

while (false !== $data = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $geometry = [
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' => [$data[2], $data[1]]
    ];
    $properties = [
        'Category' => $data[4],
        'Grid Reference' => $data[0],
        'Day' => $data[3],
        'Date' => $data[4],
        'Type of Incident' => $data[5],
        'Area' => $data[7],
        'Sex' => $data[8],
        'Age' => $data[9],
        'Members' => $data[10],
        'Hours' => $data[11],
        'Notes' => $data[12]
    ];

    $features[] = [
        'geometry' => $geometry, 
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'properties' => $properties
    ];
}

echo json_encode(['type' => 'FeatureCollection','features' => $features]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried json_encode earlier but it wraps the coordinates in " " which breaks the GeoJSON.

Comment: You should be able to cast them to numeric types to prevent json_encode from quoting them: `$coordinates = [(float) $data[2], (float) $data[1]];`.

Comment: or `(int)` rather than `(float)` if they're integer values.

Comment: That's fantastic thank you. Now I'm going to sit and read through all the code and make sure I understand it 100% so I'm not just copying and pasting. Just one point (for anyone else reading your answer), in your example code the while loop is missing a set of brackets. Should be: while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

Comment: Good point, my mistake. I haven't tested this, because I don't have appropriate input data, so there may be other little things like that. FYI, you can also do it by reversing the condition (I just edited the answer to show that).